# Regular expressions positive lookbehind + negative lookahead

Tags: c#, regex, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

Given a string `"A B C a b B"` I want to match words that are repeated (regardless of case). Expected result would be matching "a" and "b" (last occurrences of A and B) OR "A" and "B" (first occurrences)

**EDIT:** I want to match only the first or the last occurrence of the word

I know this question could be better answered by spliting the string and count each token (lowering that case).
However, I'd like to try and formulate a regex to help me find those words, just for the sake of practice.

My first atempt was: `(?=\b(\w+)\b.*\b(\1)\b)(\1)`
However it matches the first A, first B and second b (A B b).

I was thinking to somehow use positive look-behind with negative look-ahead to fetch the last instances of the repeating word: `(?<=.*(?!.*(\w+).*)\1.*)\b\1\b`
(In my head is translates to "a word that had been matched before and won't match again")

Well, it doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Is it possible to use positive look-behind and negative look-ahead this way?
Could my regex be fixed?
I've tried to solve it in C#.

**This is not homework**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting puzzle. Here's my solution:

```
(\b\w+\b)(?:(?=.*?\b\1\b)|(?<=\b\1\b.*?\1))
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cb%5cw%2b%5cb)(%3f%3a(%3f%3d.*%3f%5cb%5c1%5cb)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5cb%5c1%5cb.*%3f%5c1))&i=A+B+C+a+b+B&o=is)

The reasoning is as follows:

- Match a word: `(\b\w+\b)`
- Then either: `(?:`...`|`...`)`

  - Make sure it occurs again later on: `(?=.*?\b\1\b)`
  - Or it already occurred before: `(?<=\b\1\b.*?\1)`

    That second `\1` in the lookbehind matches the word that was just matched before. The first `\1` is the real duplicate.

---

Answer for the edited question:

If you only want to match the first occurrence of a duplicated word, we can change the above pattern a bit:

```
(\b\w+\b)(?=.*?\b\1\b)(?<!\b\1\b.*?\1)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cb%5Cw%2B%5Cb)(%3F%3D.*%3F%5Cb%5C1%5Cb)(%3F%3C!%5Cb%5C1%5Cb.*%3F%5C1)&i=A%20B%20C%20a%20b%20B&o=is)

Now the logic is:

- Match a word: `(\b\w+\b)`
- Make sure it occurs again: `(?=.*?\b\1\b)`
- And make sure it didn't occur before: `(?<!\b\1\b.*?\1)`

  (same thing than before except with a negative lookbehind)

Comment: I want to match the repeating words only once. I edited the question. Sorry.

Comment: @nocgod no problem, I've expanded the answer

Comment: @Lucas_Trezsniewski Great! I've been moving those parts around, have no idea why I didn't try the simple solution!